# Datatables - Json output - PostgreSQL - Returns null

Tags: php, json, postgresql, null, datatables

I use datatables. I use it in conjunction with a Postgresql server.
I want to take the data from the Postgresql server.
I use the script found on: http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_postgres

The script works and creates the json file. The problem is that the values on the json file are null.

This is what it returns:

```
{"sEcho":1, "iTotalRecords":4, "iTotalDisplayRecords":4, "aaData":[[null,null,null], [null,null,null], [null,null,null], [null,null,null]]}
```

Also what i don't understand is the variable `$sIndexColumn` (Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality)). I have set its value to the first column of my table e.g. `$sIndexColumn = "'Name'";`. Is this the correct use ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> To use the code on your own server, simply change the *$aColumns* array to list the columns you wish to include from your database, **set *$sIndexColumn* to a column which is indexed (for speed)**, *$sTable* to the table name, and finally fill in your database connection parameters to *$gaSql*.

**Emphasis** mine. So, `$sIndexColumn` should be a column name, not a quoted string. Try this:

```
$sIndexColumn = "Name";
```

Single quotes are used for strings in PostgreSQL (and most other flavors of SQL).

I'm guessing that you made the same quoting problem with your `$aColumns`, i.e. you did something like this:

```
$aColumns = array("'One'", "'Two'", "'Three'");
```

when you should have done something like this:

```
$aColumns = array("One", "Two", "Three");
```

You're getting three columns out but there's nothing in those columns and those column values come from here:

```
$row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
```

So if `$aColumns` is wrong then you'll get the `null`s that you're seeing.

Comment: Hi. I didn't put the quotes by mistake. Postgresql does not understand table names with capitals, you need to quote them. So here is my array variable.

 $aColumns = array( '"Name"', '"Surname"', '"Telephone"' );

If i leave it like this it returns the results i told you. If i make it $aColumns = array("Name", "Surname", "Telephone");
then it searches for field "name" not for field "Name" and returns error.

Comment: The `'"Name"'` approach looks right as the double quotes will quote the column names but maybe the PHP is getting confused. Can you have a look at what's in `$aRow` in the `while` loop at the end of that PHP file?

Comment: "Sort of correct" is better than "completely wrong" :) What is in `$aRow` in the loop? Are the keys upper case, lower case, or quoted upper case? Can you rewrite that loop to use the column positions rather than their names? You only need the names in there for the special "version" formatting but you're not using a "version" column.

Comment: Your approach was also correct!

I renamed all table columns to lowercase and used your suggestion and it worked ! 

But how can i use capital letters whithout renaming all my table columns ?

Comment: I'll ask this directly to the developer's forum. Thanks a lot ;-)

Comment: SQL really wants to be case insensitive so switching to lower case column and table names (if possible) might be your best bet for the long term, you're sort of fighting SQL by using mixed case names and this sort of thing will probably happen to you again. OTOH, whatever works and at least we know where the problem is now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use your suggestion and have all tables and column names with lowercase letters. ;-)