# Datatables - Json output - PostgreSQL - Returns No matching records found

Tags: php, json, datatables

After downloading and installing the [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) , I downloaded the file   [that can be used to connect into a postgresql database](http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/php_postgres) and properly changed the following lines:

```
$aColumns = array( "ab", "cd");

/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "id";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "bacon";

/* Database connection information */
$gaSql['user']       = "user";
$gaSql['password']   = "pass";
$gaSql['db']         = "db";
$gaSql['server']     = "host";
```

After configuring the db link i noticed the json the following values:

```
{
  "sEcho": 0,
  "iTotalRecords": 2,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": 2,
  "aaData": [
      ["bacon", "salad"],
      ["1", "2"]
  ]
}
```

Which I believe its OK ( since it returns data )

But when I open the main page ( [code can be opened here](http://justpaste.it/datatablehtml)  ) the result is **No matching records found**

I tried to find some guidance on the solution applied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859540/datatables-json-output-postgresql-returns-null/5860211#5860211) but it didn't gave me success.

What could I be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you have and extra `'` in your code near `$aColumns = `.

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels bad paste , thanks for pointing that, but still not the issue =(